# Make instance know about instance containing it

Tags: python, class, instance

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [Bar(), Bar(), Bar()]

a = Foo()
```

In this example, `Foo` has an attribute `items` that contains instances of `Bar`.

In Python 3.5, how can I do something like this:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        print(container.baz)
```

Where `container.baz` refers to the attribute `baz` in the instance of `Foo` that contains it.

---

**The Background**

I'm trying to create something where each `Bar` would have an `id` attribute, generated semi-randomly by `idGenerator()`. Part of the ID is the index of `Foo.items` belonging to the `Bar` instance, and the ID is generated from within `Bar`. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: **why?** Sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you *actually* trying to achieve.

Comment: @DeepSpace Updated my post.

Comment: You can pass the instance of `Foo` to the constructor of `Bar` and store it as an attribute there. That would create a circular reference between `Foo` and `Bar`, which is not particularly recommended but not really unheard of. I'm not sure why the question gets so many downvotes tbh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass in `self` to `Bar()`, and be done with it:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.id = generate_id(self, parent)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [Bar(self), Bar(self), Bar(self)]
```

If you can pass in more specific information other than `self`, just do so.

Python objects have **loads** of references to them created and removed all the time. In your example, you have three instances of a class contained in a list, and the list is referenced from an instance of `Foo`. But there will be other references. Like `a.items[0]`, and the Python stack, and many more, during it's lifetime. Python has no native facilities to let you discover what references exist to an object, because that'd be futile, constantly changing and outdated very, very, very quickly.

Just be *explicit*, and pass in the information you need, either as `self` (so a reference to the `Foo()` instance), or something else you need in `Bar()` to do it's work.